# SQL: Avoid circular dependencies

Tags: sql, database-design, circular-dependency

I see that most people just hate having a circular dependency in the database design. And since the support for this is "tricky" in most database engines, I was wondering if there's a way around this design:

I have a users table and a pictures table

Every picture has an userId (the user who inserted it)
Every user has a profile picture

I might just create a ProfilePictures table, but it would cause issues in some other places (like picture comments).

I'm aware that there are some other questions related to this issue, but they're more related to partent-child relationships, which is not the case here.

So, is it ok to use a circular dependency here? or if not, how would you avoid it?

Comment: So, a user may insert many pictures. A picture is inserted by exactly one user. And a user (may) have one profile picture (or none). Correct?

Comment: I wouldn't use a circular dependency unless there were absolutely no other way to do it. In 25+ years of database work, I've never seen a case where there weren't alternatives.  One problem most people don't think about (until it's too late) is that circular dependencies break a lot of third-party tools, like CASE, diagramming, and reverse engineering tools.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without circular references between tables:

```
User 
------
userid NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (userid)

Picture
---------
pictureid NOT NULL
userid NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (pictureid)
UNIQUE KEY (userid, pictureid)
FOREIGN KEY (userid)
  REFERENCES User(userid)

ProfilePicture
---------
userid NOT NULL
pictureid NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (userid)
FOREIGN KEY (userid, pictureid)        --- if a user is allowed to use only a
  REFERENCES Picture(userid, picture)  --- picture of his own in his profile

FOREIGN KEY (pictureid)                --- if a user is allowed to use any 
  REFERENCES Picture(picture)          --- picture in his profile
```

The only difference with this design and your needs is that a user may not have a profile picture associated with him.

---

With circular references between tables:

```
User 
------
userid NOT NULL
profilepictureid NULL                  --- Note the NULL here
PRIMARY KEY (userid)
FOREIGN KEY (userid, profilepictureid)   --- if a user is allowed to use only a
  REFERENCES Picture(userid, pictureid)  --- picture of his own in his profile

FOREIGN KEY (profilepictureid)           --- if a user is allowed to use any 
  REFERENCES Picture(pictureid)          --- picture in his profile

Picture
---------
pictureid NOT NULL
userid NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (pictureid)
UNIQUE KEY (userid, pictureid)
FOREIGN KEY (userid)
  REFERENCES User(userid)
```

The `profilepictureid` can be set to `NOT NULL` but then you have to deal with the chicken-and-egg problem when you want to insert into the two tables. This can be solved - in some DBMS, like PostgreSQL and Oracle - using deferred constraints.

Comment: Thanks, actually the second one is the design I have now. And I could just add the ProfilePictures table but that won't solve the issue of the circular dependencies (i.e. I cannot delete a User without deleting the picture, and I cannot delete the picture without deleting the user, so it's basically the same as having two tables and allowing null for the profilepictureid in users)

Comment: My first approach has no circular dependencies.

Comment: In the second system, if Picture(PictureID) is the primary key, the combination Picture(UserID, PictureID) cannot help but be unique too.  You seem to be insisting that a user cannot have a profile picture that they did not insert - which may be the intention.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I insisted on this Unique Key, mainly because MySQL seems to not be happy when you reference a combination that doesn't have a Unique Key defined. It may work fine in other DBMS (where the Uniqueness is implied, when the Primary Key is just a part of the referenced combo).

Comment: But you are right, I assumed that a user cannot have a profile picture that they did not insert. Perhaps this was not the intention of the OP. The references should be changed then. Nice spotting.

Comment: @willvv: Can a user have a profile picture that someone else inserted?

Answer (score 2):

If only a few pictures are stored per user, you could just have a flag in the pictures telling if a picture is the profile picture or not.

Comment: the main issue with this approach is that a user might have more than one picture set as profile picture! (this could sometimes be avoided using conditional constraint or nulls)

Answer (score 0):

Users has UserID and ProfilePictureID

Pictures

Has a PictureID, a Picture and a UserID

Delete the user and their profile picture will/can be deleted by PictureID, and any other pictures by userid if desired.

Don't even consider this circular as such.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't consider this circular"? The problem I have is that I cannot delete the user without deleting the picture and I cannot delete the picture without deleting the user.

Comment: Well if you'd have posted your schema when I answered I would have seen that. Not a design decision I'd have made, it causes problems you see. :)